# WebSocket SSL in JAVA

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, websocket

I have successfully established a WebSocket connection between a Client and the Server using this libraries:

- Client: github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client
- Server: github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket

Now I'm going to encrypt this connection whit SSL, but I haven't understand how I have to do to do this.
In particular I've seen this example (https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/blob/master/src/main/example/SSLServerExample.java included in Java-WebSocket 1.3.0) where it require a KEYPASSWORD and a STOREPASSWORD, what are they? Instead in the other library (the client) it is not clear precisely how I should do... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of **[nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client)**:

Replace `ws:` with `wss:`. For example, if the endpoint of your server is `ws://example.com/abc`, change it to `wss://example.com/abc`. In most cases, all you have to do is it.

In some cases, special setup for SSL is required. In such a case, use either of the following methods.

- `WebSocketFactory.setSSLContext(SSLContext)`
- `WebSocketFactory.setSSLSocketFactory(SocketFactory)`

See *"Create WebSocketFactory"* in README.md of [nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client) and the [JavaDoc](http://takahikokawasaki.github.io/nv-websocket-client/) for details.

Comment: But is the SSL certificate pinning possible with nv-websocket-client ?